# Как отобразить % загрузки файла

Tags: php, javascript, json

Имеется код :

```
server.upload.onprogress = function(event) {
        var proc = event.loaded / 100 * event.total;
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = '<progress max="'+event.total+'" value="'+event.loaded+'"></progress><label>'+proc+'</label>';
    };
```

Как сделать чтобы выводилось корректно % загрузи ( 10% 23% например )? А не бешеные цифры типа 2478557,2 !

Comment: `var proc = event.loaded * 100 / event.total;`

Comment: а как обрезать 45.554551 что после точки?

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы вывести без плавающей точки, используйте *либо* [`proc.toFixed(0)`](https://javascript.ru/number/tofixed), *либо* [`Math.round()`](https://javascript.ru/math.round).

```
var proc = event.loaded / event.total * 100;
```

```js
var i = 45.554551;

console.log(i.toFixed(0) + ' or ' + Math.round(i));
```

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь !

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение для вас:

```
var proc = (event.loaded / event.total * 100).toFixed(0);
```